# Wordpress Instagram Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, instagram

I'm working with a wordpress plugin called Instagrabber: [pluggin page](http://wordpress.org/plugins/instagrabber/). The plugin had been working perfectly for several months up until about a week ago when it started failing authentication while updating the image stream. At first, I thought the token expired, but after creating a few new testing accounts, the problem persisted.

I've isolated the problem to a couple lines of code in the main instagrabber-api.class.php file, pertaining to authenticating and retrieving the content:

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $request_uri, array(
        'timeout'=> 10,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'body' => $data
            )
);

$decoded_response = json_decode($response['body']);
```

This throws an 500 internal server error, and authentication fails. I've successfully authenticated using instagram's localhost setting, and connected with their API console, but when I make the request from our host, it fails.

This may not cover everything, so I'm happy to provide additional information, if needed.

** Edited ** 
Here are the values for $data and $response:

```
 $data = Array ( 

 'client_id' => $InstagramClientID,
 'client_secret' => InstagramClientSecret, 
 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 
 'redirect_uri' => $InstagramRedirectURI, 
 'code' => $auth_code 
 )
```

If I print $data, everything appears fine, with all values pulling correctly.

$response is an array using wp_remote_post default return values, which can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post) for reference. The following is what we get returned:

```
 Array ( 
      [headers] => 
        Array ( 
        [cache-control] => no-cache 
        [content-type] => text/html 
        [date] => Mon, 07 Apr 2014 13:15:33 GMT 
        [server] => nginx 
        [content-length] => 87 
        [connection] => Close ) 
      [body] =>
```

This seems to be where the 500 server error stems from. My thought is because of the Connection = Close, and empty body content.

Comment: For someone who doesn't have the plugin, it would be useful if you posted the values of `$request_uri` and `$data`.

Comment: No problem, I've added the requested values in my edited post above. Let me know if you need anything else.